# trying to do jsonp in Cakephp

Tags: json, cakephp, jsonp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x and trying to implement the jsonP but my code isn't working ...

here is my code

```
      public function backup(){
     $this->loadModel('Contact');
    $id = $this->Auth->user('idUser');
    $contacts = $this->Contact->getContacts($id);


    $allcontacts = json_encode($contacts);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $allcontacts . ')';
}
```

on my **Contact.ctp** view page

```
     $(function(){
   $.getJSON("https://localhost/myweb/api/backup&jsoncallback=?",
     function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
         );

            });
```

nothing is printing out on the console tab in firebug

Comment: do you see any output if you browse to: https://localhost/myweb/api/backup&jsoncallback=? , also why are you using localSSL?

Comment: yeah when i browser this url i can see my required result .. and also error is coming that undefined index jsoncallback in controller

Comment: Well, what does the returned JSON look like?

Comment: @Ahsan it isn't returning anything

Comment: i mean when you navigate to the URL via browser, what is the response there as in second comment you said you can see required result in browser window, I've asked about that!

Comment: i am getting the result in json .... showing me a lot of contacts in a json format

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33450/discussion-between-ahsan-and-mynameisjohn)

Comment: @ahsan sorry yesterday i went to sleep ... so u dere